# what is the equivalent to apache httpclient from Java in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

what is the equivalent to apache httpclient from Java in Python.The below is how we do in Java using httpclient

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(GET_URL);
        httpGet.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet)
```

;

Comment: You added correct tag to your question :) Take a look at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: I am new to Python , still like how Java code is written , there is a lot of understanding in the code above and below  r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()

Comment: Python equivalent: `r = requests.get(GET_URL, headers={"User-Agent": USER_AGENT})`. You can get the content with `r.text`

Answer (score 0):

In "pure" python 2.7 (I mean using only the stdlib) it would be `urllib2`, but the de facto standard is now the third-part `python-requests` package.